# Why does the recursion work this way in Go?

Tags: go, recursion

I'm learning Go to prepare for a coding interview, and there's a leetcode question for tree traversal. It works with recursion in Python, but Golang behaves differently.

I notice the elements in the **res** slice gets cleared one by one when every call stack is popped.

The original question is

[image]

The result should be [1,3,5,6,2,4], and it was returned correctly in Python, but the following Go code returns []

```
    /**
     * Definition for a Node.
     * type Node struct {
     *     Val int
     *     Children []*Node
     * }
     */
    
    func preorder(root *Node) []int {
        res := []int{}
    
        traverse(root, res)
    
        return res
    }
    
    func traverse(root *Node, res []int){
        if root == nil{
            return
        }
    
        res = append(res, root.Val)
    
        for _, n := range root.Children{
            traverse(n, res)
        }
        // the last element is removed from the slice every time when the code execution reaches here 
    }
```

------------------------------------- updates --------------------------------------

Thanks for all your answers, now I think I have a better understanding of how slice works in Go

The following code works for me now:

```
/**
 * Definition for a Node.
 * type Node struct {
 *     Val int
 *     Children []*Node
 * }
 */

func preorder(root *Node) []int {
    res := []int{}

    res = traverse(root, res)

    return res
}

func traverse(root *Node, res []int) []int{
    if root == nil{
        return res
    }

    res = append(res, root.Val)

    for _, n := range root.Children{
        res = traverse(n, res)
    }

    return res
}
```

Comment: You did not return the modified slice. Return the modified slice from traverse. A slice is a view over an array. When you append elements to the slice, it may be relocated, but the original slice still points to the old location.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider passing the `res` as a pointer *[]int instead so that the values get updated to the same slice else you are just passing a copy of it.

Comment: But isn't the 'res' already a reference to the underlying array?

Comment: @NicholasC. it's a structure that contains a pointer to the underlying array. And `append` function might return you a *new value* if it decides so. So the rule of thumb - **never** throw away the result of `append` call.

Comment: @NicholasC. Yes it is, but arrays in Go are fixed-size. Also, the length of the slice depends on the slice itself, not the array underlying it.

Comment: @zerkms, ya, you're right, the append function always returns a different array

Comment: @NicholasC. "the append function always returns a different array" --- that's not true either. Not _always_ but _sometimes_.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminating case, you're not returning the accumulator:

```
if root == nil{
  return
}
```

But...

I would use a *closure* so as to avoid cloning the slice on every recursive call (Go passes by value):

```
type Node struct {
    Val      int
    Children []*Node
}

func preorder(root *Node) (res []int) {
    var traverse func(*Node)

    traverse = func(root *Node) {
        if root != nil {

            res = append(res, root.Val)

            for _, n := range root.Children {
                traverse(n)
            }
        }
    }

    traverse(root)

    return res
}
```

Comment: "cloning the slice on every recursive call (Go passes by value)" --- there is a chance you misunderstand what happens under the hood: even though *everything* in go is passed by value, the data in slices *is not* cloned.

Comment: Hmmm... Isn't slice a reference to the underlying array?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
 s1 := []int{1, 2, 3}
 test(s1)

 fmt.Println(s1)
}

func test(s []int) {
 s[0] = 4
}
```
How come the s1 becomes [4,2,3] in this case?

Comment: "A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a pointer to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum length of the segment)." ([source](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro)). So the descriptor is passed by value (i.e. copied) but the backing array is untouched (and will be referenced by the copy of the descriptor) [playground demo](https://go.dev/play/p/YfqkXD48xM9).

Comment: @zerkms — The data in the slice **is** cloned; the date in the backing array is _not_ cloned.