# Recursive function in go is not storing changes

Tags: go, recursion, pass-by-reference

```
//Recursively set ExternalID for all Parts, PartUse, Components in Component struct
func (svc *ProductManagementClient) setExternalID(input *[]Component) *[]Component {
    for _, component := range *input {
        if component.Components != nil {
            component.Components = svc.setExternalID(component.Components)
        }
        component.PartUse.ExternalID = component.PartUse.ID
        component.Part.ExternalID = component.Part.ID
        for _, occurrence := range component.Occurrences {
            occurrence.ExternalID = occurrence.ID
        }
        component.ExternalID = "PartID:" + component.Part.ID + ",PartUseID:" + component.PartUse.ID
        zap.S().Debug("ExternalID for component:", component.ExternalID)
    }
    return input
}
```

In this function, I'm trying to set the ExternalID field for these structs, and I'm calling it from another function. The code snippet for that is below:

```
// Set externalID for each Part, PartUse and Component
for _, component := range retBOM.Components {
    component.Components = svc.setExternalID(component.Components)
}
```

The changes aren't being persisted, and I'm unable to tell why. When I look at the result, the ExternalID fields are still coming up empty. I'm writing a recursive function because the Component field is nested. How can I fix this?

*I tried to pass by reference but apparently that's not allowed in Golang.*

Comment: *"I'm unable to tell why"* -- The `component` iteration variable is a copy of the elements in the slice `input` over which you are iterating. Either use pointers, i.e. `[]*Compontent`, or re-assign the element in the slice, i.e. `(*input)[i] = component`.

Comment: Do note that the use of pointers to *slices* is uncommon, especially if the pointer is the input *and* the output. I.e. `*[]Component` is unusual as a parameter for a function that is not modifying the slice-header.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/2Abfgkc8SwQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closely related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73368460/why-does-the-recursion-work-this-way-in-go/73368512?noredirect=1#comment129570852_73368512)

But as many pointed out, you are passing the copy of the component but address of the slice.

so the fastest way to handle this is to use
`[]*Component` which in layman means a slice of pointer components

Answer (score 0):

Its because in cycle youre modifying *copy* of Component. at the end of iteration you must replace it like

```
for i, component := range *input {
    if component.Components != nil {
        component.Components = svc.setExternalID(component.Components)
    }
    component.PartUse.ExternalID = component.PartUse.ID
    component.Part.ExternalID = component.Part.ID
    for _, occurrence := range component.Occurrences {
        occurrence.ExternalID = occurrence.ID
    }
    component.ExternalID = "PartID:" + component.Part.ID + ",PartUseID:" + component.PartUse.ID
    zap.S().Debug("ExternalID for component:", component.ExternalID)
    // replace current state by new one
    *input[i] = component
}
```

or use []*Component / *[]*Component instead of *[]Component